# Solution to system of nonlinear equations

Tags: representation-theory, systems-of-equations, characters

I am trying to comple the character table of a finite group with seven conjugacy classes $c_1, \cdots, c_7$:

[Character table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6xRv.png)

If I use the orthogonality of the column vectors of table I get a system of $21$ nonlinear equations of the form
$$
k_{i, j} + r_i r_j + s_i s_j = 0
$$

where $k _{i, j} \in \mathbb{R}$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq 7$ and $i \neq j$. I do not know if it helps but I noticed that I can write evey equation as a $2 \times 2$ matrix with determinant $-k_{i, j}$:
$$
\operatorname{det}
\begin{pmatrix}
r_i & -s_j\\
s_i & r_j
\end{pmatrix}
= -k_{i, j}.
$$

I do not know how to solve this system. Can you help me?

Comment: Where did you get this table from? Is it an exercise?

Comment: Yes, it is an exercise from "A Course in Finite Group Representation Theory" by Peter Webb. Specifically, the excercise 9 from chapter 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you multiply the fifth character with the second, you obtain another irreducible character. The remaining missing character should be easy to determine.

Comment: I do  not understant why multiplying such characters gives me another irreducible character.

Comment: By 3.1.3 in your book, a product of characters is a character. If one has degree 1, then the product remains irreducible by 3.3.4. I don't know if this is mentioned anywhere explicitly.

Comment: Now I understand. I don't think that this fact was mentioned explicly in the book.

Comment: Where can I find a further explanation of such property? I don't find the property to be stated explicitly anywhere.

Comment: There are (at least) two well-known books on character theory: One by M. Isaacs, the other one by B. Huppert. Both are called "Character theory of finite groups"

Comment: Thank you very much.